# Best way to read IDataReader for WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, json.net, sqldatareader, idatareader

I have a WebApi action that returns dynamic result based on Sql query.
Currently using the following function to convert IDataReader which works fine, but it creates a Dictionary object for each row. I was wondering if there is a better way to do that.

```
private IEnumerable ReadResult(IDataReader reader)
{
    var names = new string[reader.FieldCount];
    var values = new object[reader.FieldCount];

    for (var i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
    {
        names[i] = reader.GetName(i);
    }

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        reader.GetValues(values);

        var record = names.ToDictionary(i => i, s => values[Array.IndexOf(names, s)]);

        yield return record;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach (don't exactly know how this will play together with WebAPI, but still worth a try):

```
var record = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, object>;
foreach(var name in names)
    record[name] = values[Array.IndexOf(names, name)];

yield return record;
```